# How to use the audit system of jhipster to audit password changes?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

A Jhispter-Appliction generates Audit-Events when a user logs in or enters a wrong password.
I would like to use the same system to generate events when the user changes a password, or when an admin-user changes data from another user.
How should I call the audit system?
My current idea is to call a method in the changePassword-rest-api-call and do in this method something similar as done in the `CustomAuditEventRepositoryIntTest.addAuditEvent`

```
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("password-strength", "weak");
    AuditEvent event = new AuditEvent(
        loginUsername, 
        "PASSWORD_CHANGE", 
        data);
    customAuditEventRepository.add(event);
```

Do I need to change the `CustomAuditEventRepository` or create my own version? Or do i just use the `PersistenceAuditEventRepository`?
And is there a special magic configuration so the the audit is called automatically, or do I just call it in the rest-api-method?

Comment: In UserService, publish your events and spring boot actuator will save them to repository.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like suggested by Gaël Marziou:
I publish an event, and the framework is responsible to store it into the repository (or do something else, depending on the configuraton of listeners)

In my user service, I added the following:

```
...
private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;
...
private void auditPasswordChange( User user ) {
    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(
        new AuditApplicationEvent(
            user.getLogin(), AUDIT_PASSWORD_CHANGE, "message=Changed by own user")
    );
}
...
public void changePassword(String password) {
    ...
    auditPasswordChange(user);
}
```